# escape replacement string 'read' from user

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a sed script where the replacement string comes from user input, e.g.

```
echo -n "Enter identity? "
read identity
sed -i "s:^export identity=.*:export identity='$identity':g" $CFG_FILE
```

The problem is that the user may enter a value that has special meaning to sed, for example:

```
abc:abc
```

In this case, the colon character used in the sed statement, so causes an error.

Is there a way to allow the user to enter any value, but if a value has special meaning to sed then it gets escaped?

---

Note this question is similar to, but different from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186445/escape-replacement-string-from-bash-source-file

Comment: What you are looking for is **sanatizing** inputs.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89609/in-a-bash-script-how-do-i-sanitize-user-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the variable in the replacement, you need to escape the character that represents the delimiter.  Use shell parameter expansion:

```
identity="${identity//:/\\:}"
```

This would *transform* `abc:abc` into `abc\:abc` and `abc:def:ghi` into `abc\:def\:ghi`.

Moreover, you want to use:

```
read -r identity
```

instead.  That would ensure that any backslashes in the user input do not escape any characters.