# sanitise variables sourced from another file

Tags: bash

I have a number of variables that are being source'd from an external file:

**my.sh**

```
source my.conf

sed -i "s:var1:$var1:g" $SOME_FILE
sed -i "s:var2:$var2:g" $SOME_FILE
sed -i "s:var3:$var3:g" $SOME_FILE
```

**my.conf**

```
var1=abc:abc
var2=def!123
var3=&*(!"£
```

The script that source's these variables will run into issues if any of the values contain special characters (such as the colon character):

I have seen how variables can be [individually sanitised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186205/escape-replacement-string-read-from-user), but is it possible to sanitise them all in one go?  Note that the actual variable names do not have a pattern as in the example above.

Comment: You could try `source <(sed 's/:/\\\\:/g' my.conf)` instead.

Comment: @devnull - you're a star!  I feel bad that you haven't added this as an answer so that I can +1 and accept it!

Comment: Good to know that it worked.  You could answer your own question too :)

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to credit you for your efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could *transform* the configuration file before sourcing it so that the `sed` delimiter would be escaped:

```
source <(sed 's/:/\\\\:g' my.conf)
```

The `<(command)` form is referred to as [Process Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).